# How can I get the status/progress of a QBRequest for both creating and retrieving a custom class in Quickblox?

Tags: ios, quickblox

Here is an example of how I retrieve objects of a custom class from `Quickblox`:

```
[QBRequest objectsWithClassName:@"My_Custom_Class" extendedRequest:getRequest successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, NSArray *objects, QBResponsePage *page) {
        // Success
    } errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
        // Error
    }];
```

Here is an example of how I create new objects for a custom class in `Quickblox`:

```
QBCOCustomObject *object = [QBCOCustomObject customObject];
object.className = @"My_Custom_Class";

// Object fields
[object.fields setObject:self.titleTextView.text forKey:@"Title"];
[object.fields setObject:self.bodyTextView.text forKey:@"Body"];
[object.fields setObject:self.userSession.fullName forKey:@"Author_Name"];
[object.fields setObject:@"self.username" forKey:@"Author_Username"];

[QBRequest createObject:object successBlock:^(QBResponse *response, QBCOCustomObject *object) {

    // Response

} errorBlock:^(QBResponse *response) {
    // Error
}];
```

I need to be able to get the status/progress of these, so that I can show a loading/progress bar to my users based on actual progress made.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no Statusblock callback for these two methods. You can just show an activity indicator to show the progress.